# Add wiki excerpt description to the tag auto complete dropdown on AskQuestion page

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, tag-wiki-excerpt

By adding the first bit from the wiki-excerpt behind the tag in the auto-complete dropdown, you could increase the accuracy of the initial tagging of the questions.

An example:[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can view the tag wiki excerpt by hovering over the tag that appears above the input area.

[image: hover over tag to see the wiki excerpt]

Comment: You're right! Though the use case I had in mind was the comparison of similar tags next to each other to assist choosing the most appropriate one during the tagging process. The tag-explainer-popup-description only appears when you have entered a complete tag and then only if you mouse over the tag (which probably won't be seen by most users). My intent was to aid users in the selection of the most appropriate tag _before_ they mistagged it.

Comment: @yhw42 As it is now, you can avoid to mistag a question, if you take a look at which tags are already used, which are listed on http://stackoverflow.com/tags, and see the description reported for each of them. Looking at the tag descriptions when you are trying to use a tag is probably the wrong moment to do it, also because you are doing it when you are already entering a tag name.